# define current date of kendo scheduler bound with mvvm

Tags: mvvm, telerik, kendo-scheduler

I want to define the current date displayed by a kendo scheduler like
in the JS approach:

```
$("#myscheduler").kendoScheduler({
   date: new Date("2016/5/5")
});
```

source: [telerik docu](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler#configuration-date)

I cannot find mvvm documentation for my task. This does not work:

```
<div id="myscheduler" data-role="scheduler"
                      data-date="new Date('2016/5/5')"
                      data-views="['month']"
                      data-bind="source: entries, events:{dataBound: schedulerOnDataBound}"                                                                                                                     
 >
```

I also had no success with `data-bind="value: new Date('2016/5/5')"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try simply type the date as string? Please check the demo below (works on my side):

```
   <div data-role="scheduler"
             data-views="['day']"
             data-date="2016/1/1"
```